# WPF Helper lines in Designer mode not showing any more

Tags: c#, wpf, designer

I have searched around using different terms, I don't know the correct name of what I search so it's hard to find something relevant about it.

In Winforms when you drag a control into a form and drag it around if there is another control you will see visible lines in the designer (snap lines I think) that are showing the alignment from the control you are dragging to the other. In WPF there was the same but I don't have it anymore and I can't find it anywhere in the tools/options. I did not change anything to my knowledge that would change that behavior.

Is it due to an update and they removed it or what happened that I don't have it anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See bottom, left side of the designer. There are a couple of toggle buttons there which may be of help.

Comment: OMG, I LOVE YOU SIR! It was "Snapping to snaplines" that was somehow turned off .... You have no idea how much you have helped me !